# Sorting a multidimensional array, and displaying the values from highest to lowerest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a multidimensional array, and display the values according to the highest to the lowest. How would I do that?

```
$array[0][0] = "section1";
$array[0][1] = 3;
$array[1][0] = "section2";
$array[1][1] = 1;
$array[2][0] = "section3";
$array[2][1] = 2;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
section1
3
section2
1
section3
2
```

**Need Result:**

```
section1
3
section3
2
section2
1
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by highest to lowest? Based on the result you need, I don't understand the sorting criteria.

Comment: Oh, now I see the confusion as well. Is your expected result correct? Shouldn't it be `section1` first instead of `section2`?

Comment: @PatrickLee Oh, sorry. Sam is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $b[1] - $a[1];
}
usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I mixed up section1 and section2. Sorry.